# Binomial Distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently using excel to work out the Binomial Distribution. What is the equivalent code in R that would do this, please?

The size of the random sample=30, the 0.1 is the percentage this event will occur and the 3 is the predicted value

P- Value = 1- Binomdist (3, 30, 0.1, True)

Many Thanks

Comment: `pbinom(3, 30, 0.1, lower.tail = FALSE)`

Comment: Not clear to me what we are achieving here. Probability of having no more than 3 successes?

Comment: you need the p-value of success = 3 when n = 30 and p=0.1, or the probability of observing success >= 3?

Answer (score 1):

The probability will be

```
> dbinom(3,30,0.1)
[1] 0.2360879
```

More readings on that here: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/binomial-distribution